# How to style a proportionally scaling header image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a header with image in the following HTML page:

```
<div class="wrapperHeader">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="header.png">
    </div>
    <!-- header ends here -->
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <nav class="menu">
            ...
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- menu-wrap ends here-->
</div>
<!-- wrapper Header ends here-->
```

The relevant CSS is as follows:

```
.menu-wrap {
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #808080;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.wrapperHeader {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
.header {
    width: 1210px;
    height: 192px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

When I zoom in and out the image in the header scales (up or down) faster than the menu, so I loose the proportions of the page. I would like some scaling similar to what you can see in http://www.studio-efekt.com.pl/ Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I put your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/wprvLwd8/), but I can't really see what the problem is. Could you provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sure! You can have a look here http://www.monikapolak.eu/

Comment: The header image scales faster than the rest when zooming in/out the page.

Answer (score 1):

This works for you.
The Image is placed into the empty block.

```css
.menu-wrap {
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#808080;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
    width:700px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.wrapperHeader {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:block;
}
.header {
 width:70%;
height: 192px;
margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.header img {
position: absolute;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperHeader">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="header.png">
        </div><!-- header ends here -->
        <div class="menu-wrap">
          <nav class="menu">
              ...
           </nav>
        </div>  <!-- menu-wrap ends here-->
</div> <!-- wrapper Header ends here-->
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Still the image scales faster than `menu-wrap`.

Comment: Like this?  http://leodebeer.nl/  this is my own (in progress) website :)

Comment: Exactly! Everything centered would be fine even for me.

Comment: I made  https://jsfiddle.net/u89fpy5n/7/ You only have to make the max-width attributes the same width as the image.

Comment: Feel free to vote up my comment if it helps, PS: delete all unneeded css

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check it out.

Comment: Jelle I checked your example. When you zoom in the page with Ctrl+, at a certain point the image grows more than the `div` below.

Comment: The problem still persists!